# How do I break a string in YAML and add more lines?

Tags: java, yaml

i have this string

```
private String QUERY = "| sum(increase(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{path=?}[10m]))";
```

how can i add a new line and make the sum under the |

i tried adding

```
"|\n" + 
"sum(increase(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{path=?}[10m]))"
```

but i keep getting two |-
|
then sum

i also tried to add the query provided and the outcome of it was this

```
private String QUERY = "| \nsum(increase(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{path=?}[10m]))";

outcome: query: "| \nsum(increase(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{path=/hi}[10m]))"
```

this is where the yaml gets converted to a string

```
public static List<HasMetadata> convertResourceToHashset(Object object) {
        KubernetesClient kubernetesClient = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
        try {

            // Create a YAML representation of the data
            DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
            options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
            options.setIndicatorIndent(0);
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
            String yamlString = yaml.dumpAsMap(object);

            // Remove the class name tag by converting it to a map
            Map<String, Object> yamlMap = yaml.load(yamlString);
            String finalYaml = yaml.dump(yamlMap);
            // Convert the YAML string to an InputStream
            InputStream yamlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(finalYaml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            // Load the YAML InputStream into a list of HasMetadata
            return kubernetesClient.load(yamlStream).get();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error in convert resource to Hashset : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

what im trying to achieve is how the query looks in this yaml file

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
 name: test-scale
 namespace: karavan
spec:
 scaleTargetRef:
   kind: Deployment
   name: helloworld
 minReplicaCount: 1
 maxReplicaCount: 2
 cooldownPeriod: 30
 pollingInterval: 1
 triggers:
 - type: prometheus
   metadata:
     serverAddress: http://kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus.monitoring:9090 # figure out where to update the metrices
     metricName: nginx_ingress_controller_requests
     query: |
       sum(increase(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{path="/test"}[10m]))
     threshold: "10"
```

Comment: "i tried adding..." *How* did you try this?

Comment: Unless you write the YAML by hand, generally you let the YAML implementation choose how and where it splits a string into multiple lines. Also we can't help you if you don't show *how* you write this string into a YAML file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have updated the question to clarify even more

Answer (score 0):

> How do I break a string in YAML and add more lines?

You can see how I added a new line to the string using the literal style:

```
private String QUERY = "| \nsum(increase(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{path=?}[10m]))";
```

You can see the next output:

```
| 
sum(increase(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{path=?}[10m]))
```

Comment: i dont seem to understand, youre saying the string should look like this?
```
private String QUERY = "|" +
            "|sum(increase(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{path=?}[10m]))";
```

Comment: can you check the question i reupdated it

Comment: @EliasAl-SwaisMiddleEast yes, sure. Let me also change my answer then.